# comparing string with Array using .contains() Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

moderately experienced in swift, but now diving into Arrays.

I have an array being called inside a tableview cellForRow.
The array calls several "default" items. "itemData"
User selects the entries and this gets saved to an array called "diveItemArray".

When the user returns to the same tableview, I am trying to have the checkmark load matching the diveItemArray array.

I am trying to use the .contains(separator: ) to find the match, but not working.

The below runs, but does not display the checkmarks.

```
var diveItemArray: Array<DiveItemForDiveModel> = Array<DiveItemForDiveModel>()

private var itemData: Array<String> = Array<String>()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DiveItemCell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = itemData[indexPath.row]

    let names = diveItemArray.map { $0.name }

    let test2 = names.joined(separator: " ")

    if itemData[indexPath.row].contains(test2) {
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

    }

    return cell
}
```

If I print itemData, I get:

```
["", "Fun Dive", "Qualification Dive", "Refresher Dive", "Educational Dive", "Night Dive", "Deep Dive", "Wreck Dive", "Cave Dive", "Ice Dive", "Freshwater Dive", "Test Dive"]
```

if I print diveItemArray, I get:

```
["Deep Dive", "Wreck Dive", "Freshwater Dive", "Refresher Dive"]
```

if I print test2, if get:

```
Deep Dive Wreck Dive Freshwater Dive Refresher Dive
```

How can I get the the match to display checkmarks?

Comment: Good catch.  I copied that from the viewDIdSelect.  Let me try removing that.

Comment: updated it, but still no go.  See above change

Comment: Since cells are reused at least you have to implement an `else` branch to set the accessory type if the condition is **not** met

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Fixed that too.  Any suggestions on the issue of checkmarks?

Comment: shouldn't you check `names.contains(itemData[indexPath.row])`? Anyway what you are doing is searching for `Deep Dive Wreck Dive Freshwater Dive Refresher Dive` `String`

Comment: That was it.  Thank you!!!  Please put this as the answer